# Looking for a workaround for dynamic variable declaration in a for loop

Tags: java

I have a number of repetitions of a task I would like to put in a for loop. I have to store a time series object as an `IExchangeItem`, a special class in `openDA` (a data assimilation software).

This is one of the tasks (that works):

```
HashMap<String, TimeSeries> items = new LinkedHashMap<String, TimeSeries>();
...
TimeSeries tsc1Q = new TimeSeries(time,value);
id = "Q1";
tsc1Q.setId(id);
this.items.put(id,tsc1Q);
IExchangeItem c1Q = new TimeSeries(tsc1Q);
```

What changes across the tasks is the `id` of the time series object and the name of `IExchangeItem`. I have to create a new `IExchangeItem` object for each time series.

This is what I tried in the for loop:

```
HashMap<String, TimeSeries> items = new LinkedHashMap<String, TimeSeries>();
...
TimeSeries temp;
for (int i = 0; i<readDataDim[0]; i++) {
    value[0] = values[i];
    id = exchangeItemIDs[i];
    temp = new TimeSeries(time,value);
    temp.setId(id);
    this.items.put(id,temp);
    IExchangeItem <??> = new TimeSeries(temp);  //* How can I handle this line?
}
```

I know I cannot use dynamic variable names in java and that arrays, lists, or maps are commonly used to work around this issue (this is why I used `<??>` in the code snippet above. However, I'm a relative beginner with java and I have no clue how I can work around this specific problem since I have to have a new invocation of `IExchangeItem` for each time series.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221447/reference-type-variable-declaration-inside-a-for-loop) I take it that my `IExchangeItem` created in the for loop will not be accessible outside the for loop so how can I initialise `n` replicates of `IExchangeItem` outside the for loop?

Edit:
Does a `HashMap` create `n` instances of `IExchangeItem` if I try something like this?

```
HashMap<String,IExchangeItem> list = new LinkedHashMap<String,IExchangeItem>();
```

Comment: Can't you have IExchangeItem array or list?

Comment: @zubergu Does this list then create `n` instances of `IExchangeItem`s? The thing is that `IExchangeItem` is some sort of global class (where I have to admit I don't understand every detail...) and I'm not sure I can access these `IExchangeItems` if I store them in a list. They might not be visible to the rest of the code then, or are they?

Comment: Where the IExchangeItem is being used?

Comment: In different classes outside the one where I define it.

Comment: From where the readDataDim[] is being populated?

Comment: @mabe no hard feelings, but you definitely have to read tutorial on java data structerus, I see no point in rewriting it to you here.

Comment: I read this a few lines above (in the part I put `...`) from a .mat file using jmatio.

Comment: @BilboBaggins I read this a few lines above (in the part I put ...) from a .mat file using jmatio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one suggestion, try to write a separate method when you can pass the size of the array or a fixed number (based on array), then you created a hashMap and add that many number of instances with its keys, and values, cannot post this as a comment and hence posting it as an answer.

Try to create a new method using the value of readDataDim[0] value,

```
public Map<String, IExchangeItem>  createAndInitialzeMap(int maxValue) {
    Map<String, IExchangeItem> map = new HashMap<>();
    String temp = "tempName";
    for(int i =0; i < maxValue ; i ++ ) {
            map.put(temp+i, new IExchangeItem());
    }   
    return map;
}
```

return this way you can initialize your map along with its variable name and you can use it in your app anywhere. However I would consider refactoring if such code exists and time permits.

One more thing you should read about hashMap. :) :)

Comment: Thanks. I did not write the method but have the loop inline and my unit tests still run without errors or failures. So this does the job. These HashMaps . . . I have been reading java documentation but to be honest most of it still sounds like a foreign language to me.

Comment: No worries my friend, eventually you will get it.. :) btw welcome to the world of Java :) :)

Comment: And I would still insist to create a new method, it makes code more maintainable :)